# Automatic index creation for Unique constraint

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2008

The database used is Microsoft SQL Server 2008.

When I create a UNIQUE constraint on a column, will automatic indexing will be created or I create an Index for the column manually?

From below para from http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms175132(v=sql.105).aspx

*When you create a UNIQUE constraint, **a unique nonclustered index** is created to enforce a UNIQUE constraint by default*

So it means some index (not sure what's nonclustered) at least is created. Please correct my understanding.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes the UNIQUE constraint is a logical concept that for SQL Server (and most DBMS systems) also involves a PHYSICAL index creation to enforce it.

It otherwise becomes counterproductive to maintain, since every single insert requires a full table scan just to make sure it doesn't violate the constraint.